# Security concerns for jsRender inside node.js process

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, eval, jsrender

I have node.js app like chat, and i need to make something similar to templates. So any user can make own template that will be rendered later.

So i have two ways:

1. I can go with regular string replace and replace predefined parameters with actual values
2. I can use `jsRender` and just allow user to specify `jsRender` templates with disabled code executions.

I more prefer second approach as it's more flexible, but i'm concerned that user might specify some evil javascript code that will be executed by jsRender on server side and it might leak data.

So is `jsRender` is secure to run on node.js server and allow users to specify their own templates that will be executed on server side?

Comment: What kind of templates, like html templates?

Comment: It's more like json request that may contain properties specified by user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JsRender is designed to make it impossible for user-defined templates to run arbitrary code.

You must of course leave the *allowCode* settings option at its default value, false (See http://www.jsviews.com/#settings/allowcode and http://www.jsviews.com/#allowcodetag@tmpl).

Users can include rich template expressions in the template, but they won't be able to insert code that accesses any variables (or runs any methods) that are outside of the template scope. They can only access the contextual data/model, use the standard operators, and use any helper methods and variables which you (the author) decide to provide.

Comment: Hi Boris, your answer is very useful. Thanks for it and for JsRender itself!